# Implications of the continuum hypothesis outside set theory

Tags: logic, soft-question, set-theory, examples-counterexamples

Just out of pure curiosity, are there any examples of the consequences of accepting (or accepting its negation) the continuum hypothesis outside set theory?

I know for Zorn's lemma, which is equivalent to AC, there are many applications in algebra, analysis, and topology, but I did not really find many for the continuum hypothesis beyond pure set theory.

Comment: Did you mean to say "accepting the continuum hypothesis or its negation"? Not accepting the continuum hypothesis is not the same that accepting its negation.

Comment: @jjagmath Yeah, so what does not accepting the continuum hypothesis mean then?

Comment: @wsz_fantasy Not-accepting is compatible with fence-sitting.

Comment: Let's say you're working in ZFC. Accepting the CH means you're now working in ZFC + CH. Not accepting the CH means you're still working in ZFC. Accepting the negation of CH means that you're now working in ZFC + $\neg$CH.

Comment: You can find some statements from other areas related to the CH [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/368559/foundational-results-dependent-on-equivalent-to-the-continuum-hypothesis-or-its)

Comment: @jjagmath I see. Thank you for the clarification.